Custom Stripe wordpress Integration error: IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element
Actual error IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element. Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted.
doing Custom coding in Wordpress.
Getting these logs in console when clicking Submit Payment button:
enter image description here
My Stripe.js:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('DOM content loaded');

    // Only proceed if the "card-element" exists on this page.
    if (document.getElementById('card-element')) {
        var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');
        var elements = stripe.elements();

        // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
        var style = {
            base: {
                fontSize: '16px',
                color: '#32325d',
            },
        };

        // Create an instance of the card Element and mount it.
        var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
        card.mount('#card-element');

        console.log('Card element created and mounted');

        // Form submission handling.
        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        if (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action.

                // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks.
                document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = true;

                stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                    if (result.error) {
                        // Inform the user if there was an error.
                        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;

                        // Re-enable the submit button if there's an error.
                        document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = false;
                    } else {
                        // Send the token to your server or handle the success case.
                        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            // Submit the form with the token ID.
            var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
            var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
            hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
            form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

            console.log('Form is being submitted with Stripe Token:', token.id);
            form.submit(); // Submit the form
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Stripe card element does not exist on this page, skipping Stripe JS initialization.');
    }

    const addToCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');

    addToCartButtons.forEach(button => {
        if (!button.dataset.eventAttached) {
            button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                console.log('Add to cart clicked');
                var productId = event.target.getAttribute('data-product_id');
                var data = {
                    'action': 'add_to_cart',
                    'product_id': productId,
                    'quantity': 1
                };

                console.log('Sending add to cart request');
                fetch(stripe_params.ajaxurl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                    headers: new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    }),
                    body: new URLSearchParams(data).toString()
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('Add to cart response:', response);
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log('Product added to cart', response.data);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to add product to cart', response);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
            });
            button.dataset.eventAttached = "true";
        }
    });
});

in the page elements card element is there and I have verified too, but problem and solution both are unclear
Tried GPT various times, but problem remains,
in the network tab I have a failed request with title https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-card-42314505c22e1be2d1e9866ec407b315.html

Tokens API is deprecated and no longer recommended as it doesn't support authentication. I'd recommend checking the latest integration guide for payment integration.
